# Como ignorar uma linha de uma consulta no banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, select, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou tentando desenvolver um codigo para criar tabelas dinâmicas com php e mysql, utilizando um banco de dados asterisk. Minha primeira dificuldade é que o registro das ligações são duplicados (ou quadruplicados), caso a ligação seja interna. Por exemplo, se eu usar o comando:

```
SELECT calldate, src, dst, duration, disposition
FROM cdr 
ORDER BY calldate DESC
LIMIT 8;
```

Esse resultado é obtido:

```
+---------------------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| calldate            | src  | dst  | duration | disposition |
+---------------------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| 2020-12-15 08:43:27 | 5003 | 5010 |      505 | ANSWERED    |
| 2020-12-15 08:42:32 | 5001 | 5006 |       34 | ANSWERED    |
| 2020-12-15 08:41:42 | 5001 | 5006 |       34 | ANSWERED    |
| 2020-12-15 08:39:15 | 5006 | 5010 |       34 | ANSWERED    |
| 2020-12-15 08:38:26 | 5006 | 5010 |       34 | ANSWERED    |
| 2020-12-15 08:36:30 | 5001 | 5008 |       36 | ANSWERED    |
| 2020-12-15 08:36:06 | 5004 | 5001 |        0 | BUSY        |
| 2020-12-15 08:35:46 | 5004 | 5001 |       20 | BUSY        |
+---------------------+------+------+----------+-------------+
8 rows in set (0.09 sec)
```

Como posso contornar isso?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT src, dst, ...

Comment: A tabela que você postou na pergunta não tem registros duplicados. Duplicado seria se todos os dados de um registro (linha) fossem iguais aos de outra linha. Como as _calldates_ são todas diferentes, não está ocorrendo duplicação de registros.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o [distinct](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) para distinguir os resultados do select, porém nesse caso acredito que você deseja distinguir apenas pela coluna "disposition", uma vez que é a única duplicada/quadruplicada no exemplo.

Mas acredito que o mais correto seria você realizar uma tratativa na sua tabela para evitar registros duplicados, podendo ser feito com a constraint [unique](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp).

Espero ter ajudado, caso não, por favor complemente sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```sql
SELECT max(calldate) calldateMax, src, dst, duration, disposition
FROM cdr 
group by src, dst, duration, disposition
ORDER BY calldateMax DESC
```